# need to find if a specific number is existing or not in a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new in javascript and maybe the below code has some return error. what I trying to do is find a specific number in a JavaScript array.

```js
const numberList = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function includes(arrays, searchElement) {
  for (let elements of arrays) {
    if (elements === searchElement) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
console.log(includes(numberList, 3))
```

Comment: JavaScript array [already has an includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Also, you get `false` because `return` immediately ends the function. Thus you only get the *first* result of the loop.

Comment: you can use `indexOf` to check whether value exist in the array or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return when if the condition is `false`. Instead you can return `false` from outside of the loop:

```js
const numberList = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function includes(arrays, searchElement) {
  for (let elements of arrays) {
    if (elements === searchElement) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(includes(numberList, 3))
```

Though you can use the *built-in* `includes()` to achieve the same:

```js
const numberList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const IsExist = (numberList, search) => numberList.includes(search)? true : false;
console.log(IsExist(numberList, 3));
```

Comment: You should still return `false` to be consistent with the boolean results. But that has to happen *after* the loop.